# How to do "try/finally" in C++ when RAII is not possible?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, destructor, raii

I'm coming back to C++ from a heavy C# background and I've inherited some C++ codebase which I think might not have been in line with the best C++ practices.

For example, I'm dealing with the following case (simplified):

```
// resource
class Resource {
 HANDLE _resource = NULL;
 // copying not allowed
 Resource(const Resource&); 
 Resource& operator=(const Resource& other);
public:
 Resource(std::string name) { 
  _resource = ::GetResource(name); if (NULL == _resource) throw "Error"; }
 ~Resource() {
  if (_resource != NULL) { CloseHandle(_resource); _resource = NULL; };
 }
 operator HANDLE() const { return _resource; }
};

// resource consumer
class ResourceConsumer {
 Resource _resource;
 // ...
 public:
  void Initialize(std::string name) {
   // initialize the resource
   // ...
   // do other things which may throw
 }
}
```

Here `ResourceConsumer` creates an instance of `Resource` and does some other things. For some reason (outside my control), it exposes `Initialize` method for that, rather than offering a non-default constructor, what apparently violates the RAII pattern. It's a library code and the API can't be refactored without making it a breaking change.

So my question is, how to code `Initialize` correctly in this case? Is it an acceptable practice to use an in-pace construction/destruction and a re-throw, like below? As I said, I came from C# where I'd simply use `try/finally` or the `using` pattern for that.

```
 void ResourceConsumer::Initialize(std::string name) {
  // first destroy _resource in-place      
  _resource.~Resource();
  // then construct it in-place
  new (&_resource) Resource(name);
  try {
    // do other things which may throw
    // ...
  }
  catch {
    // we don't want to leave _resource initialized if anything goes wrong
    _resource.~Resource();   
    throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: Possibly change the code to use `std::unique_ptr<Resource>` in `class ResourceConsumer`?

Comment: destructors do not have arguments.

Comment: @Mine, do you mean I'd need to have a local instance of `std::unique_ptr<Resource>` in `Initialize` and then do something like `unique_ptr.swap` at the end? I like this idea, although I don't like extra allocations and de-referencing for such a thin object.

Comment: @avo I mean to change `Resource _resource;` to `std::unique_ptr<Resource> _resource;`, then in `Initialize()` you can do `_resource.reset(...)`

Comment: Most objects should have a "valid, but containing nothing" state for exactly this reason. Think of `int fd = -1;`, etc.

Comment: What you do struggle with there is lack of assignment of Resource. If the Resource was move-assignable there were no need for unique_ptr.

Comment: But ***do*** add a non-default constructor! Why should *new* code not be able to profit from better concepts, whereas existing code still can use the `initialize` function. Best mark it deprecated as well (possibly conditionally on C++ version: `#if __cplusplus >= 201402L [[deprecated]] #endif void initialize();`

Comment: While the original setup is *horrible*, IMO it's not helpful to tell the poster to refactor/modify code where he says "It's a library code and the API can't be refactored without making it a breaking change."

In such cases the best thing to do is to wrap the interface you are given in a cleaner one, and use the cleaner interface exclusively. Specifically, wrap the classes you are given in cleaner ones that obey RAII.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make `Resource` a moveable type. Give it move construction/assignment. Then, your `Initialize` method can look like this:

```
void ResourceConsumer::Initialize(std::string name)
{
    //Create the resource *first*.
    Resource res(name);

    //Move the newly-created resource into the current one.
    _resource = std::move(res);
}
```

Note that in this example, there is no need for exception handling logic. It all works itself out. By creating the new resource first, if that creation throws an exception, then we *keep* the previously created resource (if any). That provides the strong exception guarantee: in the event of an exception, the state of the object is preserved exactly as it was before the exception.

And note that there is no need for explicit `try` and `catch` blocks. RAII just works.

Your `Resource` move operations would be like this:

```
class Resource {
public:
    Resource() = default;

    Resource(std::string name) : _resource(::GetResource(name))
    {
        if(_resource == NULL) throw "Error";
    }

    Resource(Resource &&res) noexcept : _resource(res._resource)
    {
        res._resource = NULL;
    }

    Resource &operator=(Resource &&res) noexcept
    {
        if(&res != this)
        {
            reset();
            _resource = res._resource;
            res._resource = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~Resource()
    {
        reset();
     }

    operator HANDLE() const { return _resource; }

private:
    HANDLE _resource = NULL;

    void reset() noexcept
    {
        if (_resource != NULL)
        {
            CloseHandle(_resource);
            _resource = NULL;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: This is great, I've been trying to come up with something like this but didn't have this firm grasp of what you're saying. One thing I still don't get is how you've dealt with an exception during the creation of `res` at the first line of `Initialize()`, didn't the OP wanted it caught? Or are you saying that if catching it was only allegedly for the RAII then no use for it anyways and better let it go back up the callstack?

Comment: Oh silly me, I see it all now, the OP himself rethrew it... Then I'll take it as a yes to my previous question : )

Comment: A great answer. This should convince the owner of `Resource` class to make it moveable. If however they resist to refactor it, would `unique_ptr` be the second choice for me?

Comment: Just to be explicit about: While *generally* leaving an object as is in case of exception is the better way to go, if leaving an object empty on failed initialisation in specific case is more appropriate for whatever reason (e. g. compatibility to previous behaviour), of course one still can call the member's reset function before creating the new object...

Comment: @avo: If the owner of `Resource` won't make it C++11 moveable, then they should at least make it de-facto moveable. That is, give it `reset` and `release` methods with behavior similar to that of `unique_ptr` (both should be `noexcept`). Then, instead of using `_resource = std::move(res)` to assign the member, you do `_resource.reset(res.release())`.

Comment: @NicolBolas, thanks again! Is there an existing template class in standard C++ library to resemble the `Resource` behavior? Like something parametrized with C++ labdas to create/destroy a specific resource?

Comment: @avo: Well, yes. It's called [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). You can make them use things that aren't actually pointers using the `deleter::pointer` member of the deleter class you provide to `unique_ptr`. However, I generally find doing that to be unwieldy and confusing if the type being wrapped is not actually a pointer. Also, it doesn't save much typing to write something like `Resource` out by hand.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I've posted a [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52285163/2674222) on this. I remember reading something about a standard proposal for such class but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm leaving this answer here just for reference, as an example to an answer that didn't seek hard enough into the OP's full scenario. As the OP themselves *rethrew* the exception and clearly just used the try/catch clause for alleged *RAII* purposes, having no other use for it.

**Nicol Bolas's answer is definitely the way to go.**

Original answer:

If all you want to make sure is that the destructor for `_resource` is being called in case *anything goes wrong*, then you could have `Resource _resource` some unique smart-pointer, and then make a temporary smart-pointer in the scope of `ResourceConsumer::Initialize()` and eventually move the temp to `_resource` if all goes well. In all other scenarios the scope will be exited before the move and *stack unwinding* will call the appropriate destructor for the temporary.

Code example, in an attempt to stick as much as possible to your snippet in the question:

```
// resource consumer
class ResourceConsumer {
 template<class T> using prop_ptr = std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<T>>;
 prop_ptr<Resource> _resource;

 // ...
 public:
  void Initialize(std::string name);
};

void ResourceConsumer::Initialize(std::string name) {
  // first destroy _resource in-place      
  std::experimental::get_underlying(_resource).reset(); // See 'Note 2' below.

  // then construct it in-place
  auto tempPtr = std::make_unique<Resource>(name);
  // do other things which may throw
  // ...

  // Initialization is done successfully, move the newly created one onto your member
  _resource = move(tempPtr);

  // we don't want to leave _resource initialized if anything goes wrong
  // Fortunately, in case we didn't get here, tempPtr is already being destroyed after the next line, and _resource remains empty :-)
}
```

Note 1: Since I realized the `catch` clause was just rethrowing, we are getting the same effect without it just fine.

Note 2: You can safely remove the call to `reset()` in case you want your exception semantics to be such that in case of failed initialization then no change is made to *resource*. This is the preferable way, a.k.a. *strong exception guarantee*. Otherwise leave it there to guarantee empty resource in case of initialization failure.

Note 3: I'm using a `propagate_ptr` wrapper around `unique_ptr` to preserve const-qualification of `_resource` member under `const` access path, i.e. when working with a `const ResourceConsumer`. Don't forget to `#include <experimental/propagate_const>`.

Comment: An alternative, with equivalent behaviour but perhaps slightly more efficient, is to use [std::optional](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) rather than `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Another advantage: you get a "not initialised" marker for free: `_resource` member containing `nullptr`...